# How can I Patent features, functions, and devices without details?

Tags: patentability

I invented a chair with a mechanism that has functions and features ( using a controller ).
The problem is there are a lot of ways or designs to make each detail.
 I wrote the provisional patent application as "a method for making" without reaching to details like screws positions and controller details.
Is it enough to be protected?

Answer (score 1):

You try to make the claims as broad as possible without covering anything from the prior art and only provide concrete examples in the description. Then you make narrower versions of the claims as dependent claims in case you missed some prior art.

-> You can patent anything as broad as you can describe it without including prior art in the claims and only have to provide a few examples to support the claims.